# Typescript: How do I refactor [Record<string, unknown> | null, Record<string, unknown> | null]?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my function:

```
function foo(
  hello: fooOptions = {}
): [Record<string, unknown> | null, Record<string, unknown> | null] {
```

Is it possible to refactor this line to make it look slightly better?

```
[Record<string, unknown> | null, Record<string, unknown> | null]
```

Comment: Maybe you can write 
`
[Record<string, unknown>?, Record<string, unknown>?]
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yest ,it is possible:

```js
type fooOptions = {}

type Nullable<T> = T | null
type Obj = Record<string, unknown>;

function foo(
  hello: fooOptions = {}
): [Nullable<Obj>, Nullable<Obj>] {

  return null as any
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nA8mYBLOA7AzlAvFAbwF8AoE0SKAOQFcAbOgQwCM6IAeAFQD48pOoAHygZ6dcuGiJmAKz4AlCAGM4AJwAm7LMFWoMAcwA0UGhgDWGOAHcM3ANxkYppWkywEAChJQoACwgMcABc7kgo6Nh8xCQAlCEA2rQMLGzs0jLcxklMrBzp3AC6hGQ%20qhDANKoYImJQjDiMGCAkREA)

More generic solution:

```js
type fooOptions = {}

type Nullable<T> = T | null
type Obj = Record<string, unknown>;

interface FixedLengthArray<T extends any, L extends number> extends ReadonlyArray<T> {
  0: T;
  length: L;
}

function foo1(
  hello: fooOptions = {}
): FixedLengthArray<Nullable<Obj>, 2> {

  return [{}, {}, {}] // expected error
}

function foo2(
  hello: fooOptions = {}
): FixedLengthArray<Nullable<Obj>, 2> {

  return [{}] // expected error
}

function foo3(
  hello: fooOptions = {}
): FixedLengthArray<Nullable<Obj>, 2> {

  return [{},{}] // ok
}

function foo4(
  hello: fooOptions = {}
): FixedLengthArray<Nullable<Obj>, 3> {

  return [{},{}] // expected error
}
```

Shamelesly stolen from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223)

You can also use recursion for fixed length arrays, but sometimes recursion can heat your laptop ))))

Comment: That works thanks but I was wondering if there's a better way to make it shorter. I had to do this to be able to mock a response in my unit test. Also, my linting doesn't allow any or casting but thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to create a type separately so:

```
type ReturnResponse = [Record<string, unknown> | null, Record<string, unknown> | null];

function foo(
  hello: fooOptions = {}
): ReturnResponse {
```

We could also put the type in a separate file somewhere and export it. In a separate file it would be:

```
export type ReturnResponse = [Record<string, unknown> | null, Record<string, unknown> | null];
```

and ten we would import ReturnResponse in the file where it's being used.